# Convert JsonArray to byte[] array in android

Tags: android, json, arrays, okhttp

I have the following jsonarray:

{
    "_id"   :"value",
    "data": "value",
    "array"  : [{
        "x" : "value",
        "y"  : "value"
    },
    {
        "x" : "value",
        "y"  : "value"
    }]
}

How to convert this to byte[] array ?

Comment: so you want to convert a string to a byte array?

Comment: Your questions is not very clear. Can you say why do you want to convert it to a byte array? This would help others answering.

Comment: You don't have a JSON array, but a JSON Object. Do you want to POST JSON to a webserver?

Comment: I need to convert a json array to bytearray. I am going to use OKHTTP. It takes byte array as parameter. so i need the json to be converted to byte arrya

Answer (score 4):

```
public byte[] objectToBytArray( Object ob ){
 return ((ob.toString()).getBytes());
}
```

Pass your JSONArray as the object here.